# nginx configuration: Domain working but IP address cause security warning from Chrome

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, openssl, nginx-config

I have configured HTTPS on my nginx server where I host `example.com` and `data.example.com`, and I also set up http forwarding to https. If I use the domain names as written everything works great, certificates are valid and there are no issues. However, when I type in the IP addresses of the servers, I get a NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID security warning from chrome.

I do not know if this is expected behaviour or if my configuration is not set up properly. Is this normal/expected?

Second, I am using AWS Elastic IP addresses, so if I wanted the IPs to work as well, how can I do that? When I followed some tutorial for another website (which uses apache + certbot) both the domain and the elastic IPs work, which is why I am confused now.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using nginx-certbot? iirc it doesn't allow certification to bare-metal IPs, and only to domain names, which are example.com and data.example.com in your case. Perhaps you can set up a redirect so that the IP address redirect to example.com, if that's what you want.

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you! I set it up so now the IP is redirected to example.com, which is what I wanted. In terms of overall set up this should be ok, I hope. 
I used both nginx-cerbot and ZeroSSL for testing. I had the same issue for both.